# Clearing keyboard buff in C with getchar()

Tags: c, buffer, getchar

I have this noob question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned short int main() {
    short int num_test = 0;
    char car_test;
    
    printf("Insert a number: ");
    scanf("%hd", &num_test);
    
    printf("Insert a character: ");
    scanf("%c", &car_test);

    return 0;
}
```

In the code above, `car_teste` would receive the value `'\n'`, right?
To prevent this, we should clean the keyboard buffer, right?
Well, instead of doing this:

```
char c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
```

Why we "can't" use this solution, for example?

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned short int main() {
    short int num_test = 0;
    char car_test, kb_buff;
    
    printf("Insert a number: ");
    scanf("%hd", &num_test);

    kb_buff = getchar();
    
    printf("Insert a character: ");
    scanf("%c", &car_test);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What would your second program do if the user typed "123cheesesandwich" at the first prompt?

Comment: You can use `fgets` if you don't want a loop. Although it's a bit fragile; `getline` is probably safer.

Comment: By the way, `main` returns an `int`, not a `short`. Your prototype is undefined behaviour unless your compilation environment explicitly allows that prototype.

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int`.  If you assign it to `char c`, then you may get false positives as `c == EOF` is true sometimes when `getchar` did not actually return EOF.  Never assign the value returned by `getchar` to a variable of type `char`.

Comment: Thank you all for your advices!!
I really appreciate that.

Comment: Oh! I forgot one thing...
How about scanf(" %c", &char_test)?

Comment: [`scanf` is broken as specified and should not be used at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-for-input-conversion-instead-of-scanf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to flushing the rest of the input line is correct except for the type of `c` which must be `int`:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    continue;
```

The alternative `kb_buff = getchar();` may work but the user might have entered more characters after the number before hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, which the `while` loop will consume correctly.

Note also that the prototype for your `main` function must be:

```
int main(void) {
```

Comment: Thanks!!
Also, why scanf(" %c", &char_test) is not correct?

Comment: @PedroLuiz: for the same reason stated here above: if the user typed `43 ab` when prompted to `Insert a number: `, the program will read the number `43`, then output `Insert a character: ` and `scanf(" %c", &char_test)` will read the `a` pending in `stdin`.